# "Object keyword is not defined" error in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code in typescript:

```js
const a = (b: object) => {
    console.log(b)
  }
 a({c:2})
```

Executing the above code I get:
`ESLint: 'object' is not defined.(no-undef)`.
Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, what could be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: That code is valid TypeScript ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFAIwFwxGgVgU2CgEokA+GAbwCgY6ZRIQAbfAOmZAHN1jaYAvrTgpKwDACYBxIA)). If ESLint is complaining about it, it sounds like ESLint is not configured to expect TypeScript rather than JavaScript.

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder said, it seems to be an ESLint problem. If your code works, then you can be sure it's not a TypeScript problem.
Since the object type is new, you might need to update ESLint so it knows about it.

Answer (score 1):

After setting this in eslintConfig file:

```js
"plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
```

... all works.